# Can't drop table with geography column

Tags: postgis-2.0

I imported shp to postgis 2.0.1 with shp2pgsql and chose to use geography instead of geometry. However, now when I try to drop the table, the pgadmin/sql console/phpPgAdmin freezes. I can't neither truncate it or change the columns.

Any help would be appreciated :-).

Comment: try "drop table tablename cascade;" from query window

Comment: Tried before, doesn't work.

Comment: Try to VACUUM ... Can you operates the data? ( select, update, and so ... )

Comment: Can you login into the database using `psql`?

Comment: At this point i would login to Freenode and #postgresql or #postgis and ask it there.